# Pegar tag específica do XML com o PHP

Tags: php, xml

Recebo um arquivo XML para um diretório da hospedagem e o arquivo tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
<categorias>
    <id_53>142</id_53>
    <id_89>346</id_89>
    <id_160>457</id_160>
    <id_5498>856</id_5498>
    <id_177>98</id_177>
    <id_183>22</id_183>
    <id_248>34</id_248>
    <id_184>782</id_184>
    <id_203>35</id_203>
    <id_214>743</id_214>
    <id_218>325</id_218>
    <id_219>678</id_219>
    <id_220>393</id_220>
    <id_136>177</id_136>
    <id_137>274</id_137>
</categorias>
```

Como preciso pegar apenas uma tag específica, tentei fazer do seguinte modo:

```
<?php
// gero a variável com o conteúdo do XML
$arquivo_xml = simplexml_load_file('xml_impo/cats.xml');

// Imprimo o valor da tag id_220, ou qualquer outra quando necessário
echo $arquivo_xml->categorias[0]->id_220;

##############################################
##### TENTEI TAMBEM / SEM SUCESSO
// gero a variável com o conteúdo do XML
$arquivo_xml= new SimpleXMLElement('xml_impo/cats.xml');

// Imprimo o valor da tag id_220, ou qualquer outra quando necessário
echo $arquivo_xml->categorias[0]->{'id_220'};
?>
```

**Mas na tela retorna em branco.**

Preciso sempre pegar apenas um valor, especificando no `echo` a id_00 a receber;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você carrega os arquivo via SimpleXMLElement ou simplexml_load_file ele já entra na raiz do xml, ou seja, o índice **categorias** já é o índice padrão, para pegar o id default será necessário apenas executar o seguinte comando:

```
echo $arquivo_xml->id_220
```

Caso no futuro você tenha várias categorias o certo a se fazer no xml seria:

```
<lista>
    <categorias>
        <id_53>142</id_53>
        <id_89>346</id_89>
        <id_160>457</id_160>
        <id_5498>856</id_5498>
        <id_177>98</id_177>
        <id_183>22</id_183>
        <id_248>34</id_248>
        <id_184>782</id_184>
        <id_203>35</id_203>
        <id_214>743</id_214>
        <id_218>325</id_218>
        <id_219>678</id_219>
        <id_220>393</id_220>
        <id_136>177</id_136>
        <id_137>274</id_137>
    </categorias>
    <categorias>
        <id_53>142</id_53>
        <id_89>346</id_89>
        <id_160>457</id_160>
        <id_5498>856</id_5498>
        <id_177>98</id_177>
        <id_183>22</id_183>
        <id_248>34</id_248>
        <id_184>782</id_184>
        <id_203>35</id_203>
        <id_214>743</id_214>
        <id_218>325</id_218>
        <id_219>678</id_219>
        <id_220>393</id_220>
        <id_136>177</id_136>
        <id_137>274</id_137>
    </categorias>
</lista>
```

Com esse XML acima seria necessário a posição do array, como exemplificado na pergunta, por conta do índice padrão ter se tornado o **lista**:

```
echo $arquivo_xml->categorias[0]->id_220;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliseu, você pode carregar o arquivo e lê-lo em um foreach, dessa forma:

```
<?php
   $arquivo_xml = simplexml_load_file('xml1.xml');

   foreach($arquivo_xml as $tag => $val){
      echo $tag . ' = ' . $val . '<br>';

      // Se precisar verificar alguma tag específica:
      if ($tag == 'id_220'){ echo 'TAG 220, valor: ' . $val . '<br>'; }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Realmente o código funcionaria, porém não é necessário efetuar um foreach para a leitura de um campo na raiz do xml, expliquei melhor no comentário acima.

Comment: Sim Vinicius, a sua resposta está mais ampla. O foreach serve para os casos em que não sabemos exatamente o nome das tags e precisamos percorrê-las. Eu não sei como fazer para checar se uma determinada tag existe, seguindo o seu exemplo. Seria algo assim? ```if (isset($arquivo_xml->id_220)) { echo 'Existe 220'; }``` Ou tem outra forma?

Comment: Obrigado @RodrigoTognin